# lambda expression : get a property based on another property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to build HTML in my view :

```
<div class="row contentHeaderInfo">
     @foreach (var groupedItems in Model.DSet.GroupBy(a => new {a.rowId}))
     {             
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in groupedItems)
            {
                 <li>@item.Label  @item.labelValue</li>
            }
        </ul>            
     }
</div>
```

Data inside the object where rowid = 1 :

```
groupedItems[0] = {1,"FName","ABC"}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"LaName","DEF"}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"Address",""}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"City","LosAngeles"}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"State","California"}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"Zip","90045"}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"Street","Cardiff"}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"House No","1234"}
groupedItems[0] = {1,"Apt","1"}
```

For certain `label` I want to put more than one `labelValues` inside an `<a>` tag.

For example If `@item.Label = "Address"` then I want

```
 <li> Address <a href ="blah"> 1234 Cardiff LosAngeles California 90045 </a></li>
```

And the rest (apt, house no,city, state, zip) so not appear individually. Is it possible to achieve this with lambda expression?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use @if?

```
@foreach (var item in groupedItems)
{
    @if (item.Label == "zip")
    {
        <li>@item.Label  @item.labelValue</li>
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think lambdas or linq would be a good solution, because the elements might not come in in the order you expect. Its probably better to process the object in the code behind before trying to insert them in the HTML.

Comment: thank u. sure it makes perfect sense to do this in the code behind.

Comment: You could build the string with `groupedItems.Singe(item => item.Label == "House No").labelValue + ...`. But processing the object in the code behind would be better.